# Sketch 3 text edititing

Tags: sketch-app

When I edit text in sketch, such as changing color of text. All of the text i have on the view will change colors too... How can I stop that?

Example: I have 3 text-fields on 2 separate pages, if I edit just ONE, all of them will change too...

How can I change this?

Comment: It seems you have the same Text style for the texts.
Check text styles in Inspector view (right side of the Sketch window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a frustrating limitation of Sketch, at the moment ...

#### What's happening

If changes in one place apply to others, you have text styles in use. +1 for consistency. When you make changes to any instance of that style, Sketch updates the master style and the change is populated to all other references to it.

#### The problem

Local style changes can be made within a block of text. The trouble is that text styles only understand block level boundaries. Think of InDesign or Illustrator with only paragraph styles. When you change any character in the block of text, Sketch applies that to the whole style.

#### The [lame] solution

If you want character-level style changes, you're forced to break any text style links first. It sucks, but it works.